# Why do divs go ladder while viewing on mobile?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to mark up a cross-platform website. Now I am stuck with the email sending form.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div style="margin-left: 4%;">
    <div class="caption">Имя <span style="color: #B5FFC8;">*</span></div>
    <input class="field" type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="50">
    <br><br>

    <div class="caption">Фамилия <span style="color: #B5FFC8;">*</span></div>
    <input class="field" type="text" name="last_name" maxlength="50">
    <br><br>

    <div class="caption">Е-мейл <span style="color: #B5FFC8;">*</span></div>
    <input class="field" type="text" name="email" maxlength="50">
    <br><br>

    <div class="caption">Примечание <span style="color: #B5FFC8;">*</span></div>
    <textarea class="comments" placeholder="Хочу фоток" name="comments" maxlength="140"></textarea>
    <br><br>
</div>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
.caption
{
    font-size: 4vmin; 
    color: #FFFFFF; 
    font-family: font; 
    float: left; 
    width: 15%;  
}
.field
{
    margin-left: 4%; 
    line-height: 4vmin; 
    font-size: 4vmin; 
    font-family: font; 
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 40%;   
}
.comments
{
    margin-left: 4%; 
    line-height: 4vmin; 
    font-size: 4vmin; 
    font-family: font; 
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 40%; 
    height: 20%; 
    resize: none;  
}
```

This is how it (the form) looks on a PC: [imgur](http://i.imgur.com/2iWgQqC.png)

And this is how it looks on a mobile: [imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7OpZ.png)

Any solutions possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't use `br` tags for spacing...that's what margins & padding are for,

Comment: All right. I'll replace them. But how do I solve the main problem?

Comment: it only happens when tags are not properly closed. Please show the complete source of the page. A div above might not be closed properly.

Comment: Here it is: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arkLsu2p/)

Comment: I tested in moble browser and no shifting there

Comment: @Grumpy can I PM you?